# Why are img files provided for mkusb persistent but only iso file are allowed?

Tags: mkusb

When I read the open source code for dus persitent (mkusb) it only allows iso file extensions.
[source code for 'dus-persistent'](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/dus-persistent) search for 'Not the extension'

But the very detailed explantions I find for how to create a persistent OS on the USB all have links to download  mostly img files (and a few tiny iso file options).
[detailed how to for mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

I know I can convert img to iso but no mention is made of this in anything I read.

BTW, thank you sudodus and others for all your time creating mkusb/dus

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

- **mkusb-dus** can create boot drives from iso files and [compressed] image files

  ```
  file.iso
  file.img
  file.img.gz
  file.img.xz
  ```

  by *cloning* (and there is a special case to extract `windows.iso` files). The shellscript [dus-live](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/dus-live) is used for that purpose.
- Persistent live drives can be created by [dus-persistent](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/dus-persistent) from iso files.
- "But the very detailed explantions I find for how to create a persistent OS on the USB all have links to download mostly img files"

  I would explain it like this: Any system can be cloned to an image file (which in turn can be compressed). Those are links to image files of persistent live systems, which can be cloned by `dus-live`.

  The reason to create such images is that if the computer running an installed Ubuntu system in UEFI mode, it will not be possible to install and use the package `grub-pc` to make the target persistent live drive bootable in BIOS mode (because there is a conflict with `grub-efi`). But in a persistent live Ubuntu, both `grub-pc` and `grub-efi` can be installed alongside each other. 
  *So it is possible to create systems that boot also in BIOS mode from a persistent live system running in UEFI mode.* And if you have a fast internet connection, it is convenient to download a compressed image file and clone it.
- The manual

  ```
  man dus
  ```

  may add details to this explanation.

### Edit 1: bugfix to make mkusb explain and help solve this issue

Thinking twice about your question, I realize that this is confusing. So I have started to improve the code in the menu part, the shellscript [dus](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/dus).  Thanks for asking this question. It helps me improve mkusb :-)

Since you are a coder, I want to explain what I am doing. It is not uploaded yet, but I am modifying the function `p_persistent` which prepares for the call to the shellscript `dus-persistent`. The version number will be updated to 12.1.3.

There is output, a zenity window and red text to the console window. The variable `src_orig` is reset to zero length.

[image]

I am also adding code to skip to cloning (calling the function p_live) in the main section of dus (near the end of the shellscript file), if dus is called with a file name as parameter, and the file extension is not iso.

```
if [ "$source" == "" ]
then
 p_starter
elif [ "${source/.iso}.iso" != "$source" ]
then
 p_live
else
 p_install
fi
```

### Edit 2: mkusb 12.1.3 is uploaded

I hope that the new version, mkusb 12.1.3, will make things less confusing. It is uploaded to `ppa:mkusb/unstable` and to [phillw.net](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/). Please try it and report back :-)